# 3rd Party dependencies and SVN Integration with Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: winforms, svn, dependencies, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm assessing moving from TeamCity to VSTS and there are two steps I have in my pipeline that I'm not sure how to setup in VSTS.

1. **How do I include 3rd party dlls in my build?** Currently we use a tool that must be installed in the Developer's computers that has separate dlls for x86 and x64. The x86 are included in the project and are needed for the designer, but the x64 are copied from the Program Files folder with an after-build command in Visual Studio. For it to work in TeamCity the tool was installed in the server, so the same after-build command copies the dlls into the build directory as in any other developer computer.

   I don't see a way to achieve this in VSTS without including the x64
   dlls in the source code, which isn't desirable due to the tool's
   license.
2. **How do I publish to SVN?** Currently our binaries are hosted in an SVN server. In TeamCity I have a PowerShell script that (in short) updates the SVN local repo in the server, copies all the files from the build directory into the SVN repo and commits the changes.

Answer (score 2):

### Storing your dependencies

Lot's of options available here:

- Put them in a NuGet package and store them in VSTS Package Management. Have your build restore the package during build.
- Put them in Source control, either SVN or TFVC and fetch them during the build.
- Store them in Azure Blob storage and fetch them on-demand by downloading them at the start of your build.
- Use a custom build agent (Azure VM?) and install the software and the VSTS build agent onto it.
- Store them as Build Artefacts in one Build Definition and fetch them using the [Fetch Build Artefacts](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bool.fetch-build-artifact) task, which is available from the marketplace.

I'm not sure what kind of license issues you're facing, but I'd expect that each has the same issues if you're not allowed to put the binaries anywhere other than on a licensed machine. Maybe the vendor offers a better option or can be persuaded to offer a Cloud/VM license option.

### Publish to SVN

I don't see why the same PowerShell script couldn't be used. Though I'd recommend not to alter your repository from the build pipeline. It makes future CI/CD scenarios much harder. You can attach the binaries as Artefacts to VSTS Builds and that way they can also easily be linked to Release pipelines. You may need to fetch the latest version of svn and store it somewhere in order to run your script. When running on a Azure VM, you can simply install SubVersion directly to the agent.

There is no built-in task available.

Comment: This answer is very helpful, I'll try to implement it and come back to mark it as the answer. +1 in the meantime. Thanks.